# Django use dynamic choices in model by foreignkey

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I have a model; for concern to this question it matters two field one is foreignkey to other model Plan and other is choicefield as shown below:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        (1, 'A1'),
        (2, 'A2'),
        (3, 'B1'),
        (4, 'B2'),
    )
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES, default=3)
    has_plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Below is my Plan model:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    PLAN_CHOICES = [(1, "Individual"), (2, "Company")]
    plan_name = models.IntegerField(choices=PLAN_CHOICES, default=2)
    plan_validity = models.IntegerField(default=180, help_text="Days after plan expires")
```

I want to update `CHOICES` which are to be available in `category` field of `MyModel` depending on selection of `has_plan`.
Consider if `has_plan` points to `Plan` object with `plan_name`; (2, "Company") then `CHOICES` are to be updated to:

```
CHOICES = (
        (1, 'A1'),
        (2, 'A2'),
        (3, 'A3'),
        (4, 'B1'),
        (5, 'B2'),
    )
```

I can achieve this in views with help of form fields but in that case I have to handle it for view and admin both hence I am looking for a better and simpler way to achieve this.

I am able to raise error with `clean()` method in model but I want to update `CHOICES` instead of just raising an exception.

---

## Update:

While creation of first entry I have set up multi-part form and achieved the solution for creation, but for editing in Django Admin, custom view and it seems that I have to handle both separately.
Instead of doing that I want a way so that I can update it once so that for create and edit in either django admin or custom view I just have to override single method.

Comment: you are selecting the has_plan on front-end? If its correct, then use jquery or javascript to update the select box options.

Comment: but I wan to also handle it in django's default admin view and I have to work on that too, so I am looking for a way that somehow if I can change/update CHOICES then I don't have to handle both view and admin seperately

Comment: In my opinion, you can't do that. But I am not sure, search on internet.

Comment: may be this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877686/update-django-choice-field-with-database-results

Comment: @Sagar I already mentioned in question that I am already able to use it with form but it makes me total 4 cases to handle create and edit in UI, create and edit in admin

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be interactive (i.e. when user changes `has_plan` in UI, category available choices change) you need to implement some client side logic. If its the case I suggest that you to just add a `clean` method to your model to check correctness of `category`, `has_plan` pair. `clean` method will be called in Django admin model forms too.

Update question/comment if somehow `has_plan` has a fixed value and you need another solution.